# Computing similarity score for all user pairs

Tags: performance, machine-learning, similarity, recommendation-engine

I have a data set containing 200,000 users, 25000 items, and 5 million ratings. I have to calculate the similarity score (by using either cosine or pearson correlation) of all possible user pairs. I have code written in c# and when ever i run it, I get memory overflow error. I have tried almost every solution (x64 application, increased heap memory etc). My PC configuration is (core-i7 3.4 GHz, 12 GB DDR3, 2TB HDD). 
Is there any resource which can help me to complete this task?

Answer (score 1):

... that said, I'm going to try to answer what you actually asked.  You failed to supply your code or your error message, so I'm taking a shot at the actual problem.

The number of possible pairs of N users is N(N-1)/2; for large values of N, this is effectively N^2 / 2.  For 2E5 users, this comes out to 2E10 possible pairs: 20 billion pairs.  I'd say that your minimal storage is the user IDs at 32 bits each, plus 4 bytes for the similarity measure.  That's 12 bytes per pair, giving us 240Gb of memory.

You haven't said a word about your algorithm, your data approach, or language you're using.  If you're trying to do all of this calculation in RAM, of *course* you're blowing your memory limit!

You're well into the range of "big data".  Start your search with those tools.  I don't know your resources for the project, and tool recommendation is well outside the realm of StackOverflow.

Granted, if you're careful with the algorithm, you'll be able to handle this.  You keep only the bare user information in memory, perhaps the ratings keyed by user ID.  When you compute a similarity, you buffer it to write to disk.

Is there more processing you have to do after you compute the similarities, or is the task finished by writing the file?  If you need to do more, you'll probably want a big-data tool set with good ETL support and data access capabilities to fit all of the project facets you haven't described.